# React-virtualized InfiniteLoader not rendering anything

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

As the title suggests, InfiniteLoader is not rendering any items. I've got everything set up properly it seems, and the collection has plenty of items to render, but nothing is displaying on the page. Here's the render method:

```
render() {
    const rows = this.state.rows
    const rowsCount = this.state.hasNextPage ? rows.length + 1 : rows.length

    // Only load 1 page of items at a time.
    // Pass an empty callback to InfiniteLoader in case it asks us to load more than once.
    const loadMoreRows = this.state.nextPageLoading ? () => {} : this.loadNextPage

    // Every row is loaded except for our loading indicator row.
    const isRowLoaded = ({ index }) => !this.state.hasNextPage || index < rows.length

    // Render a list item or a loading indicator.
    const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style }) => {
      if (!isRowLoaded({ index })) {
        console.log("LOADING") // NEVER GETS CALLED
        return(
          <div style={style}>
            Loading...
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        console.log(rows[index]) // NEVER GETS CALLED
        return(
          <MyRow key={index}
            row={rows[index]} />
        )
      }
    }

    console.log(rows) // SHOWS AN ARRAY WITH PLENTY OF ROWS
    return(
      <InfiniteLoader
        isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
        loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
        rowCount={rowsCount}>
        {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
          <AutoSizer>
            {({ height, width }) => (
              <List
                height={height}
                width={width}
                ref={registerChild}
                onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                rowCount={this.state.totalCount}
                rowHeight={46}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
              />
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a Plnkr that repros this problem

Comment: @brianvaughn I'll see what I can do!

Comment: @brianvaughn https://plnkr.co/edit/TP5BTGNA0Me1Rz7Q7Ge9?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with the height of AutoSizer being 0. Resolved by wrapping AutoSizer in a div with a set height.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how you figured this out if you still remember. It seems like such a random bug